# ScalaMock: Mocking a Trait with initializations via lazy val

Tags: scala, unit-testing, mocking, traits, scalamock

I've the following trait which I want to mock:

```
trait TraitA extends TraitB {
   private lazy val internalObject = new ServiceA()
   internalObject.setSomeVal("someVal")
   internalObject.setSomeOtherval("someOtherVal")
   private lazy val anotherObject = new ServiceB()

   def functionA(paramA: typeB): typeC = {
       // some code using internalObject & anotherObject
   } 
}
```

When using ScalaMock, I try to do

```
val mockTraitA = mock[TraitA]
```

it fails with `java.lang.NullPointerException` as probably it is not able to initialize the mock version of this trait properly due to the presence of private lazy val's ?

What could be the correct way to initialize such a trait?

Answer (score 1):

For `mockTraitA`, the line `internalObject.setSomeVal...` will be executed when the constructor for the trait runs. There's no way to prevent that unfortunately.

If you can, try to refactor to this:

```
private lazy val internalObject = {
  val t = new ServiceA
  t.setSomeVal("someVal")
  t.setSomeOtherval("someOtherVal")
  t
}
```